# VPN Issue..Unable to connect to VPN

Tags: vpn

I have been struggling with VPN..RISE VPN used to work like a charm in 18.04LTS .However,it's not working in 20.04LTS..Can anyone suggest any free VPN software or service and method of connecting the same?Kindly revert..

Comment: Are you asking about RiseUp.NET VPN https://riseup.net/en/vpn#download-riseupvpn ? I see they have not yet released a version for 20.04.  If that's the VPN you want, did you check bug reports at https://0xacab.org/leap/bitmask-vpn/issues ? (I'm firewalled out of being able to check at work, so can't see...)

Answer (score 0):

Riseupvpn isn't free, it's paid for with donations.
There's a known issue regarding Ubuntu 20.04, that is fixed. However, there hasn't been a new release yet. It will happen very soon though.
See https://0xacab.org/leap/bitmask-vpn/-/issues/254
There are other providers using the same software, like the Calyx Institute.